# How to view properties by image?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a website that is announcing properties in our city.

I have a database in MySQL which has one table for properties and one table for images

of the properties.

Every property has six images along its info.

When the user is giving a value for search and some results are appearing, so in this page I

need a button by the name of "View Properties by Image".

The MySQL commands i need ?

1. By clicking the button "View Properties by Image" all the searched result should be move from this page to another page.
2. In another page from searched result  I need only one one Image from each property to be show.

Can any one tell me the MySQL commands for above two ?

```
    // I have used PHP+MYSQL for building this website
    // I have used PHP+MYSQL for building this website
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a Property_ID primary key repeated as forign key in images table.

On display page link code will be

```
<a href="images.php?id=1212">Click for images</a>
```

Image Page:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE property_id='$id'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<img src='/images/$row[img_id].jpg' />";
}
```

Comment: i have eliminated "GROUP BY properties.Property ID" now its displaying 100 of pics repeated why? it should retrun one pic from each record not all of them